# Problem can't open tab panel of tabs via url in wordpress ux builder

Tags: wordpress, tabs

i 've have a problem with go to a tab panel of tabs via url.
The issue just occured when i put vietnamese title to the Tab ( english title is ok ) .
My resolution is change the code of tab , i add sanitize_title($tab['title']) at place that generating id for the tab.

I wrote this for who need or have better way for this.